# Autocomplete from start of (one of) multiple columns

Tags: python, autocomplete, pyside2, qlineedit, qcompleter

I have data with multiple columns (like "first name"/"surname" or "postal code"/"place name"), and I would now like to have (something like) a qcompleter which only matches from the start of each column.

This means an input of "a" would show the suggestions like "**A**ndrea Miller" or "John **A**dams" but not "J**a**ne Doe" or "Tom M**a**sters".

Any hints how to implements this?

Comment: You should be able to do it by setting the `filterMode` to `Qt::MatchStartsWith`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#filterMode-prop

Comment: When you say "multiple columns" do you mean that a string has several words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to disable QCompleter filtering and use a QSortFilterProxyModel to do custom filtering:

```py
import sys


from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class FilterModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._prefix = ""

    @property
    def prefix(self):
        return self._prefix

    @prefix.setter
    def prefix(self, prefix):
        self._prefix = prefix.lower()
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        if not self.prefix:
            return True
        text = (
            self.sourceModel()
            .index(sourceRow, self.filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent)
            .data()
        )
        for word in text.split():
            if word.lower().startswith(self.prefix):
                return True
        return False


class Completer(QtWidgets.QCompleter):
    def setModel(self, model):
        proxy_internal_model = FilterModel(self)
        proxy_internal_model.setSourceModel(model)
        model.setParent(proxy_internal_model)
        super().setModel(proxy_internal_model)

    def splitPath(self, path):
        if isinstance(self.model(), FilterModel):
            self.model().prefix = path
        return [""]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    texts = ["Andrea Miller", "John Adams", "Jane Doe", "Tom Masters"]
    completer = Completer(w)
    completer.setModel(QtCore.QStringListModel(texts, w))
    w.setCompleter(completer)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```